# Internal woking of Arrays.sort by debugging in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, java-8

I want to know how Arrays.sort method works internally and I started to debug the program but I am not able to stepin into the Arrays.sort method .
I am getting the following error "source not found"

However I added my project into source look up path . 
Can someone help me to debug the program so that I can know internal working of Arrays.sort method in runtime .
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B7n2ckO7qXq8Tk41OG9maTlsZGM/view?usp=sharing
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B7n2ckO7qXq8NzFQUGtpd0VTUWc/view?usp=sharing

Here goes the code to Sort array

```
   String[] stringArray = { "Barbara", "James", "Mary", "John",
            "Patricia", "Robert", "Michael", "Linda" };
    Arrays.sort(stringArray, String::compareToIgnoreCase);
    for(String s:stringArray)
    System.out.print(s + " ");
```

Thank you

Comment: off-topic ? Its related to eclipse . so I asked this question . If there was not tag associated with eclipse then I would have never posted my question .

Comment: There are 109,074 questions tagged with eclipse . And you found my question is off topic ?

Answer (score 2):

In order to solve the issue of **"source not found"** you have to attach the source file of the java which includes java file for that class.
you can check this by selecting the project in eclipse -->Build Path -->Configure Build Path.., Then select **Libraries**, then expand the JRE System Library, then expand the **rt.jar** which will show you the location of src.zip file if it is available in your jdk path.
[image: check the below images] otherwise download new jdk and use that jdk for looking into source file. Most Probably you would be using JRE which generally does not  contain the src attachment of the class files.
Moreover Internally **Arrays.sort()** uses **Merge sort** to do the sorting.

Comment: Thank you neo . Here is the src.zip file for java-8 https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B7n2ckO7qXq8bm9PbzRPMi14ejQ/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Neo . I am now able to see how Arrays.sort() method works but I am not able to see the values of the local variables  when debugging the code . Consider sorting an array of nine elements by Arrays.sort method . Now Internally Insertion Sort algorithm will be invoked but I am not able to see the local values of length,i , ai etc .. How to watch the values of local variables . ?